# Angular2 : Get XML data and convert it to JSON

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to angular2 and want XML to be converted to json. I use get method to receive it. issue i everytime i have received data in json directly.

please help me with working example. below is my XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <catalog>
```

Comment: You said `issue i everytime i have received data in json directly.` if you already receive your data in json, why do you need to parse xml?

Comment: https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Comment: @Dummy this time i came up with web service which has XML data instead of JSON

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(xmlDoc) {
    var result = { catalog: [] };
    var books = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var book = {};
        book.id = books[i].getAttribute("id");
        book.author = books[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].textContent;
        book.title = books[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent;
        book.author = books[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].textContent;
        book.genre = books[i].getElementsByTagName("genre")[0].textContent;
        book.price = books[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].textContent;
        book[publish_date] = books[i].getElementsByTagName("publish_date")[0].textContent;
        book.description = books[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].textContent;
        result.catalog.push(book);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with npm module instead of Javascript because

This is TypeScript & not JavaScript
while serving this would work, but while making a build or distribution it wont work as it will give error xml2json is not defined as it is available only in javascript & Not in TS or at the time of transpilation.(happened in my case)
I did something like this.

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray : false});
//used xml2js parser from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)
//and in my service i used this 
this.http.get(this.newsURL)
                .flatMap(res=>{
                        return Observable.fromPromise(this.getJSON(res.text()))
                })
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

Edit :

this.getJSON() is a function which converts XML-> JSON().

```
  getJSON(xmlText){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        parser.parseString(xmlText,function(err,result){
            if(!err){
                resolve(result.rss.channel.item);
            }else{
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    })
  }
```

And the required imports are

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray : false});
```

Comment: where should i write this code "var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitArray : false});"

Comment: @Jay : at the service method where u make ur http call which returns XML. here `this.newsURL` is the http URL.

Comment: should i pass that inside any of look events like ngOnInit

Comment: No u should do it in ur service file

Comment: @Jay please see Edit.